# jQuery device orientation remove div

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is to set a timeout when the mobile device it is at some angle and remove a div. My problem is that the clearTimeout doesn't work as expected.

```
// here
if(window.DeviceOrientationEvent) { 
    // also here
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
      var beta = event.beta;
      $('#beta').text("Beta: " + beta);
      var timeout = null;
      if (beta > 10) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('#alpha').remove();
        }, 2000);
      }else{
        clearTimeout(timeout);  
      };
    }, false);
}
```

beta is the angle in degrees the device is tilted front-to-back and it changes at every milisecond or so ...

Am I missing something.

var timeout is not local. I tried to define it outside where the comments are now. // here and // also here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `timeout` is a local variable. It is reinitialized on each event. To keep this variable move it to a parent scope.

For example:

```
if(window.DeviceOrientationEvent) { 
    var timeout = null;

    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
      var beta = event.beta;
      $('#beta').text("Beta: " + beta);
      if (beta > 10) {
        if (!timeout) {
          timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
              $('#alpha').remove();
          }, 2000);
        }
      }else{
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
      };
    }, false);
}
```

UPDATE

Each `timeout = setTimeout` overrides old timeout values. So there should be `if` that checks whether `timeout` already set.

Comment: In that case something wrong with events or event data. Try to debug code or add `console.log` and trace `beta` values.

Comment: Seems I find out what the problem could be. Please check out my updated code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for explaining it ... It is ok now